# xcode little icon - what does it mean? and why are they not copied into app

Tags: xcode, ios4, xcode4

[image]

I have no idea what these little A and ? mark mean, I do know that the ones with the ? are not in the budle, however they are in the xcode list, they are editable, they are not read only, i see them as marked to be copied into the bundle (as it is phonegap and the whole www dir should be copied)... but somehow it's not going.... what do these little icons mean? A (archive??!?!) ? = (no reference or something...?)

Comment: ps I have tried re-adding all the files to create references, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are for source control. If you've created a new project in Xcode 4 and not unticked the relevant box, you have a GIT repository automatically.

'A' means that the file is to be added to the repository when next you commit. '?' means that you've added the file to your project but you haven't yet told Xcode what you want to do with respect to source control. You can set what you want to do by right clicking the files or by selecting them and going to File -> Source Control.

In any case, they're completely unrelated to how the project is built.

Comment: thank you for the fast reply and clear answer! But how come this file is not added to the build? any idea?

Comment: found it, somehow I had to add it first (select file - right click - source control - add) then it will be copied into the build